# What is resetting the value of the iterator in this for-loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, memory-corruption

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int SIZE = 5;
    double x[SIZE];
    for(int i = 2; i <= SIZE; i++) {
        x[i] = 0.0;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
...

If SIZE is initialized to a different value, the iterator will iterate until it is one short of that value and then reset back to zero. If the array of x is changed to data type int, the loop does not get stuck on itself. If the assignment value to x[i] is changed to any non-zero number, the value of is changed to garbage during the last run of the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int SIZE = 5;
    double x[SIZE];
    for(int i = 2; i <= SIZE; i++) {
        x[i] = 1;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:
2
3
4
1072693248

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int SIZE = 5;
    int x[SIZE];
    for(int i = 2; i <= SIZE; i++) {
        x[i] = 1;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:
2
3
4
5

Comment: `i <= SIZE` should be `i < SIZE`. Your platform has a stack that likely grows **up** so you by overwriting past your boundaries you're actually overwriting `i`, the next automatic var on the stack past `x[]`, and thus restarting your loop.  Isn't undefined behavior *fun* ?? Regarding why `int x[]` doesn't exhibit this, its all UB, but just for fun check what address `&i` and `x+SIZE` report. I bet on your platform the difference is wide enough to squeeze in an additional `int`.

Comment: @op - your first example, the output starts at 3, is that really the case, or is it a typo (should start at 2)?

Comment: @WhozCraig - let me hazard a guess concerning the difference between the UB using "int x[]" instead of "double x[]", the op is likely running on a 64bit arch which aligns arrays on 64bit boundary by default, a 5 element integer array will take up 6 (32bit) integers.

Answer (score 4):

You are writing past the end of the x array.  x[] ranges from 0 to SIZE - 1 (or 4), and you let your index i == SIZE.

So, the behavior is undefined and coincidentally, you are overwriting i when you write x[5].

Use a debugger.  It's your friend.

Answer (score 2):

for(int i = 2; i < SIZE; i++) // i <= SIZE will write beyond the array

Answer (score 2):

Your current array is of size 5. Arrays are 0 indexed:

```
1st element   last element
0    1  2  3  4
```

You're iterating past the end of your array (`i <= 5`), which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Your end condition is wrong. Use i < SIZE

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int SIZE = 5;
    double x[SIZE];
    for(int i = 2; i < SIZE; i++) {
        x[i] = 0.0;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```